# My Domain Is Getting Blocked As Gambling

Tags: firewall, domain

I have a site at http://slotted.co.  Some of my would-be users complain that their company firewall is blocking access.  At least one user told me it was flagged as a gambling domain, which it is not.  What can I do about this?

Incidentally I own some other domains, such as signupster.com, which redirect to my site.  I wonder if a quick workaround would be to make that my main domain and have slotted.co redirect?

Obviously I prefer in the long terms that slotted.co is considered clean.

Comment: Ask your customers to figure out what filtering system they use?  Contact the filtering company and them request the site classification be checked.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES  It sounds more like he's talking about web filtering (to me), so I don't think MTAs have anything to do with it.

Comment: Ah my apologies - I just assumed it was e-mail related (don't know why tho) Comment removed!

Comment: Have you considered getting a domain name that doesn't look like it's for gambling? Long term you may find that to be the best and most reliable solution.

Answer (score 4):

You need to contact the vendors of the firewalls in question to get your domain re-categorized.

It's not listed as a gambling domain by Websense, so there's one off the list.

Comment: Any idea where you can get a list of these vendors?